# Matplotlib fill area under curve between two x values only

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'd like to fill the area under some curve between two values on the horizontal axis only. I tried

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

x = np.linspace(-4,4, 10000)
nVals = [norm.pdf(i,0,1) for i in x]

line = plt.plot(x,nVals)

plt.fill_between(x,nVals,color = '#111111',where = x > -3 and x < -2)
plt.axis([-4,4,0,.5])
plt.show()
```

but it returns

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I don't understand this message; when I run

```
z = -2.5
print z > -3 and z < -2
```

Python *does* understand what I mean and prints

`True`

So why doesn't this work with `fill_between` and how can I solve that?

Comment: Include a minimal source-code snippet that can be executed by itself to produce the error.

Comment: @farenort: I wish this were a requirement for posting questions.

Comment: In this case the minimal code is `x = np.arange(7)` `x < 5 and x > 2` so it is not a huge burden.

Comment: @farenorth: agree, I should have posted a complete code snippet rather than a single line. I added it to my OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurred because

```
x > -3 and x < -2
```

is an ambiguous numpy expression, so it raises the error.  Instead you want

```
(x > -3) & (x < -2)
```

Other options are to use [`logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) or [`bitwise_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) (or even `*` should work).